# SD Card formatting problem

Tags: link2sd, sony-xperia-tipo, sd-ext

Hi I have a SD card 8 Gb and when I format it into 2 partitions (*1 Fat32 and 1 ext2*) My phone shows

> Unfortunatelycom.erricson.usbux is stopped

My phone

- Sony Xperia Tipo St2l1
- Strontium *class 4 * 8Gb Sd

Answer (score 0):

link2sd is largely an abandoned app, it hasn't been updated to deal with changes in MM and looks like it never will be. I still use it all the time though and will continue to, for the purpose of merging duplicate system apps.

I have also used a second partition with the app on my older devices in the past, I have had a lot of stability issues with the apps using the sdcard partition so I'll recommend not using it -- instead, do as I do and merge duplicate apps, and convert other apps that'll fit in your system partition to a system app. there's a couple things to watch out for:
1. never ever merge Google Play "Services" it causes major problems.
2. link2sd doesn't check if there's enough free space, so keep an eye on that yourself.
3. some roms (I think odexed) will clear the app's data when merging/converting, so if there's essential data on an app you're going to work with, back it up with titanium backup, then covert, then restore "data only"

if you still intend to create a second partition, it'd be best to use Aparted
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted

and the "second partition" must be created as the first partition, the actual second partition created to be your general storage use, otherwise link2sd won't detect them properly

edit:
wowowow I call the app abandoned after like a year of no updates, then only a few hours later it gets updated, and promises another update with "comprehensive support for MM and N" just my luck lol

Comment: Thnx but I figured it I was just partitioning in logical